# In AngleSharp, how can I create DOM elements using string?

Tags: c#, anglesharp

Is there a way to create DOM elements using string in AngleSharp? For example:

```
var result = document.Create...("<div id='div1'>hi<p>world</p></div>");
```

Answer (score 4):

This is possible using a document fragment.

There are multiple possibilities how to use a document fragment, one way would be to use fragment parsing for generating a node list in the right context:

```
var context = BrowsingContext.New(Configuration.Default);
var document = await context.OpenAsync(r => r.Content("<div id=app><div>Some already available content...</div></div>"));
var app = document.QuerySelector("#app");
var parser = context.GetService<IHtmlParser>();
var nodes = parser.ParseFragment("<div id='div1'>hi<p>world</p></div>", app);
app.Append(nodes.ToArray());
```

The example shows how nodes can be created in the context of a certain element (#app in this case) and that the behavior is different than, e.g., using `InnerHtml`, which would remove existing nodes.

Hope this helps!